# Why is it called 'discrete' mathematics?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, terminology, math-history

I understand why you would refer to mathematics which concerns itself with all of the numbers on the number line as 'continuous' but why would you refer to countable or finite mathematics as 'discrete'? Like it's the mathematics no one talks about? Where does this labeling come from?

Comment: "Discrete" $\neq$ "discreet"!

Comment: Oh, wow. I see that now. Thank you.

Comment: @Asal: [Some things are both!](http://i.imgur.com/lJrFq.jpg)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh wow that made my day.

Comment: A little googling reveals that both words come from latin *discretus* meaning *separate*.

Comment: The notion of “discreet mathematics” is a standing joke among mathematicians, at least the ones I know.

Comment: The Pomona College math club used to have T-shirts that said "Mathematicians do it discretely and continuously"...

Answer (score 2):

As the online dictionary at m-w.com says, "discrete" means anything constituting a separate entity or anything consisting of distinct or unconnected elements.